# How to log express route to a file if a user access it?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make it such that whenever a user accesses a specific route, to write/append to a file. I want to put the code inside of the route "myroute". My concern is that if multiple people are accessing my express application there may be some file access/write issues.

I desire the following sample output in the file:

```
Accessed <current date>
Accessed <current date>
Accessed <current date>
Accessed <current date>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run certain code for a certain route every time, I suggest creating middleware for it.

http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

```
var app = express();

app.use('/specific/route', function(req, res, next) {
  //add your code to run every time route is hit
  next();
}

app.get('/specific/route', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('hello world');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```js
var app = express();

var logger = function(request, response, next) {
  var accessedPath = request.path;

  // do something with the accessed path
  next();
}

app.use(logger); // for all routes.

app.use('/admin', logger); // for specified routes
```

In your intended output, you can add another column to specify the particular user accessing the specified route.

**File Access/Write Issues**

 Without any investigation or much thought. You could use some **queuing** system if your access log must be a file. 
Your **logger** would be something like this:

```js
var logger = function(request, response, next) {
  var accessedPath = request.path;

  // get the user info
  // get datetime/timestamp/date/time Date.now()
  // add userinfo, accessed path and timestamp to the queue.

  next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [express-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston) npm library

```
const routeWhitelist = ['/user', '/login'];

app.use(expressWinston.logger({
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
  ignoreRoute: function (req, res) {
    return routeWhitelist.indexOf(req.path) === -1;
  }
}));
```